# Access local folder in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, folder-access

I want to create a function to read files from the folder one by one in the colab.
I have tried below that i.e. I uploaded my folder into My Drive and then tried to access it from there.
But still, it is showing the error.

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

mypath = "/gdrive/My Drive/resume pdf" #enter your path here where you saved the resumes
onlyfiles = [os.path.join(mypath, f) for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath, f))]
```

Error-->

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a7a8abc74cc6> in <module>()
      1 mypath = "/gdrive/My Drive/resume pdf" #enter your path here where you saved the resumes
----> 2 onlyfiles = [os.path.join(mypath, f) for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath, f))]

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/gdrive/My Drive/resume pdf'`enter code here`
```

I have crossed check that there is a folder named "**resume pdf**" in my drive.
So How can I upload a local folder and access each file of it one by one in colab??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mounted it at `/content/gdrive`, but you try to access it at `/gdrive`, that's the error.

Just change to

```
mypath = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/resume pdf"
```